# changing the text of asp label

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to change the text of label using jquery

```
function openMe(p_whoIs) {
          var $img = $(p_whoIs.alt).clone();
          $("#Label1").text($img);
          $("#dialog").dialog("open");
      }
```

now when i give the any value in text of label it change the value like

```
$("#Label1").text("img");
```

and var $img is also working fine i have checked it with other control but when i assign this value to label text it display [object object] not the variable $img value. So how to do that??

Comment: Please, rephrase your question. It is not clear what you are asking...

Comment: i want to change the value of label text with var $img.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because `$img` is a jQuery object, not string. You need to extract some string value out of this object, like `src` or `id` or..

It seems you are trying to extract the `alt` property:

```
var altText = $(p_whoIs).attr("alt");
$("#Label1").text(altText );
```

Comment: Thanks.Its working but i have some confusion why it is working with div tag like $("#div").append($img).text;  this give the right answer.

Comment: In that case you are actually appending (adding) an `img` element into a `div` and then extracting the text content of that div.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pull the text from a property of `$img`, whatever that variable is. If it is an HTML input, then in jQuery, you would use:

```
$img.val()
```

so that your code from above would be:

```
function openMe(p_whoIs) {
      var $img = $(p_whoIs.alt).clone();
      $("#Label1").text($img.val());
      $("#dialog").dialog("open");
  }
```

This is as close as I can get without knowing what the `$img` object is.

Comment: $img is storing the ALT property of IMG HTML tag.

Answer (score 0):

**Put asp label control in div tag then use following code**

`$("#DivID span").html($img.val());`